# Elementary real function that is increasing and positive?

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

What are some increasing and always positive functions that is *not* an exponential function and very simple?

I think it might be very difficult to find a simple function satisfying these two criteria. Here is my informal reasoning. The function $f$ is increasing and has a lower bound at zero. Suppose $f(x)\to 0$ when $x\to-\infty$ This implies that $f'(x)$ cannot be large when $x\to -\infty$. It should be the case that $f'(x)\to0^+$ when $x\to-\infty$, which suggests that when $x$ is moving from $-\infty$ to $0$, the big picture of $f'(x)$ must be increasing. Repeating this logic we have $f^{(n)}(x)$ to be increasing and $f^{(n)}(x)\to 0$ when $x\to -\infty$. This seems like an exponential function.

One cadidate is the arctan function, but trigonometry functions are just a form of exponential function.

Comment: *How* would you express $\arctan$ as an exponential function?

Comment: Are you allowing piecewise-defined functions as valid answers?

Comment: It cannot be a polynomial or a rational function.  So what else can you try?

Comment: @GEdgar Why it cannot be polynomial or rational?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $\arctan(x)= \frac{1}{2i}\log \left( \frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)+k$

Comment: @Dan Preferably not

Comment: For a polynomial or a rational function $f$ we must have $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)$  [or one is $-\infty$ and the other is $+\infty$.]  This is not possible with a strictly increasing positive function.

Comment: @HighGPA: All polynomials are either not increasing (even degree) or not always positive (odd degree), so don't satisfy the question's requirements.

Comment: @GEdgar The inverse of $y=x/(x^2-1)$ might work but it seems not elementary.

Comment: @HighGPA That inverse is just solving $(x^2-1)y-x=0$ for $x$ which is just a quadratic equation—definitely elementary, although it ends up not satisfying the desired conditions.

Comment: @GregMartin A similar version below: $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ works!

Answer (score 2):

Positive linear combinations of exponential functions (and constants) are also in this category, as are products and roots of such functions, so there can't be too narrow a description. There are also hyperbolas such as $x + \sqrt{x^2+1}$, and thus we get further combinations like $\sqrt[7]{x + \sqrt{x^2+1} + 2e^{3x} + 4e^{5x} + 6}$ and $(x + \sqrt{x^2+1})(e^x+2)(\arctan(3x)+4)$. Probably there are many others as well.

Comment: $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ seems very nice!